# Core data - Deny delete rule causing errors

Tags: xcode, ios5

I have a core data app thats working fine. I'm now trying to add delete rules into a couple of the relationships
Entity 1 has a set of Entity 2

If entity 1 is deleted and it has some entity 2 objects, deny delete, otherwise allow.
Entity two can be deleted without worrying about Entity 1

I have the relationship on entity 1 set to Deny, and entity 2's set to nullify

I'm currently getting an error when trying to delete entity 1
[quote]Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1600 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)" UserInfo=0x1e882f40 {NSValidationErrorObject= (entity: Factory; id: 0x1dda43e0 [/quote]

Do i have to do something else to get it working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deny rule does not work as you are expecting. From Apple's documentation:

> If a rule is Deny, then before you delete an object you must remove the destination object or objects from the relationship, otherwise you will get a validation error when you save.

Unfortunately the deny rule does not prevent the deletion, but causes validation error. So you should manually check if the relationship is empty before deletion.

Comment: would be great if you give url to the documentation

Comment: So the deny deletion rule should be viewed as more of a safety net that wont allow you to delete data you don't want deleted?

Answer (score 2):

You will generate a 1600 error when the following is true:

- A **Deny** delete rule is in effect in the relationship from Entity 1 to Entity 2
- You've deleted an Entity 1 object
- There is a related object at Entity1.entity2
- You attempt to save to context the persistent store

Before you perform the deletion of the Entity 1 object you should check that Entity1.entity2 is null. If it's not, do either of these options:

- Skip deletion of the Entity 1 object, or,
- Nil out the Entity1.entity2 object then delete the Entity 1 object

Comment: Found it, NSValidationRelationshipDeniedDeleteError

Answer (score 1):

The error happened to me after I had deleted `detail` object which had `nullify` rule on a relation to it's `master`. In same time the `master` had `cascade` rule on a relation to `details`. The error  disappeared after I had changed the `detail`'s  rule from `nullify` to `no action`.

It still looks strange to me. Can't understand the cause for the error.